# How to filter nested objects with Stream?

Tags: java

I want to filter nested objects with using Stream API. Problem is there are too many nested classes and with below method I am writing too many duplicate code.

Is there any way to handle this stream without duplicate codes?

```
public class Country{
    Map<String, City> cities;
}

public class City{
    Map<String, School> schools;
}

public class School{
    String name;
    String address;
    Model model;
}

public class Model{
    String name;
    Teacher teacher;
}

public class Teacher{
    String name;
    String id;
}
```

My Stream;

```
country.getCities().values().stream().foreach(
     (City city) ->
         city.getSchools()
             .entrySet()      
             .stream()
             .filter(schoolEntry -> schoolEntry.getValue().getName().equals("test")) 
             .filter(schoolEntry -> schoolEntry.getValue().getModel().getName().equals("test2"))
             .filter(schoolEntry -> schoolEntry.getValue().getModel().getTeacher().getName().equals("test2"))
             .foreach(schoolEntry -> {
                  String schoolKey = schoolEntry.getKey();
                  resultList.put(schoolKey, schoolEntry.getValue().getModel().getTeacher().getId());
              })    
);
```

Comment: @CodeMatrix I can't use map method becase I am using schoolEntry object at the end of the stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a method to use it as `Predicate` to filter the schools.

```
public static boolean matches(School school, String schoolName, String modelName, String teacherId) {
    return school.getName().equals(schoolName) 
            && school.getModel().getName().equals(modelName) 
            && school.getModel().getTeacher().getId().equals(teacherId);
}
```

Applying this to the stream:

```
public static Map<String, String> getSchoolAndTeacherFrom(Country country, Predicate<School> schoolWithModelAndTeacher) {
    return country.getCities().values().stream()
            .flatMap(c -> c.getSchools().entrySet().stream())
            .filter(s -> schoolWithModelAndTeacher.test(s.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, schoolEntry -> schoolEntry.getValue().getModel().getTeacher().getId()));
}
```

Using this like that:

```
    Country country = <county>
    Predicate<School> schoolWithModelAndTeacher = school -> matches(school, "test1", "test2", "test2");
    getSchoolAndTeacherFrom(country, schoolWithModelAndTeacher);
```

Some further thoughts:

If the map `schools` uses `School.getName()` as keys, then we can write:

```
public static Map<String, String> getSchoolAndTeacherFrom(Country country, Predicate<School> schoolWithModelAndTeacher) {
    return country.getCities().values().stream()
            .flatMap(city -> city.getSchools().values().stream())
            .filter(schoolWithModelAndTeacher::test)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(School::getName, school -> school.getModel().getTeacher().getId()));
}
```

Assuming that school names and teacher ids in a country are unique (while model names are common), the filtering would result in a single value if any. But then there is no need for `Map` as result type. A result of type `Entry<String String>` would do it.
And if the parameters of the predicate are still known (school, model, teacher), then this whole thing is just a question whether there is a given teacher on a given school for a given model in a certain country. Then we can write it even shorter:

```
public static boolean isMatchingSchoolInCountryPresent(Country country, Predicate<School> schoolWithModelAndTeacher) {
    return country.getCities().values().stream()
            .flatMap(c -> c.getSchools().values().stream())
            .anyMatch(schoolWithModelAndTeacher::test);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a "bigger lambda":

```
.filter(schoolEntry -> {
    School value = schoolEntry.getValue();
    return value.getName().equals("test")
        && value.getModel().getName().equals("test2")
        && value.getModel().getTeacher().getName().equals("test2")
}
```

Alternatively you can also create a `makePredicate` method inside the `School` class like so:

```
public static Predicate<School> makePredicate(String first, String second) {
    return (school) -> school.name.equals(first) && this.model.getName().equals("test2") && this.model.getTeacher().getName().equals("test2");
}
```

And use it as a filter predicate:

```
.filter(School.makePredicate("test", "test2"))
```

<sub>replace the name with a more appropriate name if you can find one</sub>

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a Predicate based on the condition you want to make a filter on the stream

```
Predicate<School> func1 = (school)-> "test".equals(school.name)
        && "test2".equals(school.model.getName())
        && "test2".equals(school.model.getTeacher().getName());
```

an then you can easily achieve your aim by:

```
country.cities.
        entrySet()
        .stream()
        .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
        .flatMap(x->x.schools.entrySet().stream())
        .filter(s->func1.test(s.getValue()))
        .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, schoolEntry -> schoolEntry.getValue().getModel().getTeacher().id));
```