# Java Stream filter nested objects return top level fields

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a following hierarchy in my model:

```
class Item {
    String name;
    ...
    List<SubItem> subItems;
}

class SubItem {
    String name;
    ...
    List<String> ids;
}
```

I'd like to find an `Item` and its `SubItem` where `subItem.ids` list contains some specific id and return a `Pair` of `Item.name` and `SubItem.name`. I assume all names and ids are unique, so I'm interested only in the first result.

I can do this using two `foreach` loops:

```
for (Item item : items) {
    for (SubItem subItem : item.subItems) {
        if (subItem.ids.contains("some value")) {
            return Pair<String, String>(item.name, subItem.name)
        }
    }
}
```

I was wondering if I can achieve the same result using Java 8 [Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)?

I found this answer [How to filter nested objects with Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52308856/how-to-filter-nested-objects-with-stream), but I need to return some *top level* fields (*names*) as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `flatMap`:

```
return items.stream()
            .flatMap(i -> i.getSubItems()
                           .stream()
                           .filter(si -> si.ids.contains("some value"))
                           .map(si -> new Pair<String, String>(i.name, si.name)))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);
```